# Is there are way to avoid prefetching ids from a sequence to batch insert records in Oracle db 11.2.0.4 with ojdbc6.jar

Tags: jdbc, batch-processing, oracle11gr2

I have a sequence which generates the primary key for a table. Using jdbc, I am trying to batch insert into the table. Is there a way I can avoid prefetching the sequence?

Oracle database 11.2.0.4
ojdbc6.jar

Some of the stack overflow posts indicate that Oracle 12c does not supported '#getGeneratedKeys()' method on statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trigger on the table to populate the primary key column from inside the database, avoiding the need for a round trip to fetch the keys and then insert them.

For example, if your table is called MYTABLE then ...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  MYTABLE
  before insert on MYTABLE
  for each row  
begin   
  if :NEW.MYTABLE_ID is null then 
    select MYTABLE_SEQ.nextval into :NEW.MYTABLE_ID from dual; 
  end if; 
  end;
```

If you need the value of the key in your application after the insert, you can use a RETURNING INTO clause on the insert statement to both do the insert and get the key back to your application layer in a single statement

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/returninginto_clause.htm

If you want to avoid the trigger, you can just use sequence.nextval in the insert statement for example

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (my_id, first_name, last name) value (MYSEQUENCE.nextval, ?, ?) RETURNING MY_ID into ?
```

Comment: I prefer not to use trigger, as it is a side effect that application layer would be unaware of. Yes, using _MYSEQUENCE.nexval_ is the way to go.  But, if I use `INSERT INTO MYTABLE (my_id, first_name, last name) values (MYSEQUENCE.nextval, ?, ?)` and use jdbc prepared statement. Can I get the all the generated primary keys using `getGeneratedKeys()` as specified by JDBC 4.0 Spec?

Comment: The documentation does agree with the other SO questions that the feature is not supported for batch updates.. http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/jdbcvers.htm#JJDBC28105.  Have you considered using a global temp table as a workaround... Insert into the GTT, select back the primary keys, and then do a INSERT INTO .. FROM ... to copy the GTT to your main table. Then commit to get empty the GTT (use on commit delete rows)

Comment: Thanks for answering. Considering the volume of records that I am planning to insert, 500k, a GTT would be equivalent to using a sequence. With a little more browsing I figured that, either I should change the data definition and use application generated UUID to avoid the additional round trip or I could use https://community.oracle.com/thread/338591.